# Q: UITests - How to get collectionCell element inside collectionView nested with TableView cell?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, xctest

I'm the beginner of UITests. Currently, I have an issue that I can not access element inside collectionViewCell.

My UI elements structure:

> UIViewController

> - UITableView

> -- UITableViewCell

> ```
>    ---> UICollectionView
> ```

> ```
>     ----> UICollectionViewCell
> ```

> ```
>       -----> The element that I would like to get.
> ```

I've tried with the code below:

```
let tableCellContainer = app.tables["HomeRVMPTableView"].cells.element(boundBy: 0) // Get the first Cell of TableView
let collectionContainer = tableCellContainer.collectionViews["ContainerItemCollectionView"].cells.element(boundBy: 1) // Get the second Cell inside collectionView
let collectionElement = collectionContainer.staticTexts["BuyCashCard"]
XCTAssertFalse(!collectionElement.exists)  // FAILED
```

Is there any way to access collectionViewCell/tableViewCell easier? I'm so tired when start working UITests with that.

Comment: Looks like you *are* getting the cell if you're checking that `exists` is false and it's failing. So basically the cell *does* exist...

Comment: @Oletha So sorry about my mistake, I've updated my code above (XCTAssertFalse(!collectionElement.exists)). It still doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 2):

Thank you guys for helping me, I just found another way to access the collection view inside the tableview.

Here is my code:

```
let tableCellContainer = app.tables["MainTableView"].cells.element(boundBy: 1) 
let cell = tableCellContainer.staticTexts["Brazil"]
cell.tap()            
 XCTAssert(cell.exists)
```

Hope this will help another guy who has the same issue like me.

Answer (score 0):

For that line to fail, the collectionElement must actually exist. Replace your failing line with `XCTAssert(collectionElement.exists)`

`XCTAssertFalse` fails when the condition is true. `XCTAssert` (equivalent to `XCTAssertTrue`) succeeds when the condition is true.

Comment: I've updated my code above, XCTAssert(collectionElement.exists) still doesn't work.